# Check email at fixed interval

Tags: productivity

I'm trying to cut down the time I spend checking for new mails by having an app/tool that works like Gmail Notifier (I'm on a PC), except that it allows you to specify checks at a fixed interval or at particular times of day. I would like to know if anyone has a recommendation for such an app.

I've tried the following apps:

- Official Gmail Notifier/Talk client - Does not allow specification of interval
- GWatchman - Does not allow custom intervals (slider-based), UI looks weird when not used with the Reader notification (see image below)
- Gmail Peeper - Does not support intervals above 60 minutes

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I don't know about Windows specific, bu Chrome and Firefox have some email checking add-ons that you can set the checking interval. I, for example, use [mail checker plus](http://chrome.desc.se/), for chrome. 
Take a look [at this other one](http://www.johnvey.com/features/gmailapi/) too

Comment: I'm actually looking for something that sits in the system tray. Thanks for the suggestion anyway!

Comment: Try this other one in the Edit.

Comment: I actually found Spiffy in the meantime: http://members.multiweb.nl/kevin/spiffy/

You might want to check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Not what you're asking for, but what the heck.

I use a full-featured e-mail software, Thunderbird, which connects and downloads messages from to 2 gmail accounts and 1 yahoo mail accounts through IMAP.

It's always on, and it pops an icon whenever there's a new message in any of the boxes. It also saves time to read the messages since I don't have to load up the website. If I received a message while I'm away, the icon is always there (unlike a pop balloon that disappears). My mail is still accessible through web from work, and read/unread status keep synchronized between home and work.

To be honest, I wouldn't go back to a mere notifier.

Comment: I am a huge fan of thunderbird and find it much more useful than the GMail interface (which I use when away from my home computer) especially when dealing with multiple accounts.

Comment: I went from Thunderbird to simply using Gmail's interface a few years back, and I do prefer the latter as an e-mail client. Thanks anyway!